# I made C# script in unity for crouching and i when i press ctrl while I'm crouching it won't stand up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to stand up while I'm crouching and added it to script, however the way I did it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class crouching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool ctrlPressed = false;
    public bool ctrlPressedHalf = false;
    public bool crouchTimeRunning = false;
    public bool crouchOnCoolDown = false;
    public bool crouchAvailable = true;
    public float timer = 0.0f;
    public float waitTime = 0.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ctrlPressed = false;
        ctrlPressedHalf = false;
        if (crouchTimeRunning)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer >= waitTime)
            {
                crouchTimeRunning = false;
                crouchOnCoolDown = true;
                timer = 0.0f;
                waitTime = 2.0f;
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 20, 10);
                transform.position = new Vector3(0, 11, 0);
            }
        }
        if (crouchOnCoolDown)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer >= waitTime)
            {
                crouchOnCoolDown = false;
                crouchAvailable = true;
                timer = 0.0f;
                waitTime = 0.0f;
            }

        }
        if (ctrlPressedHalf & crouchTimeRunning)
        {
            crouchTimeRunning = false;
            timer = 0.0f;
            waitTime = 2.0f;
            crouchOnCoolDown = true;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 20, 10);
            transform.position = new Vector3(0, 11, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            ctrlPressedHalf = true;
        }
        if (ctrlPressedHalf & crouchAvailable)
        {
            ctrlPressed = true;
        }
        if (ctrlPressed)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);
            transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
            crouchTimeRunning = true;
            crouchAvailable = false;
            waitTime = 3.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

I made this `if` statement for it:

```cs
if (ctrlPressedHalf & crouchTimeRunning)
{
    crouchTimeRunning = false;
    timer = 0.0f;
    waitTime = 2.0f;
    crouchOnCoolDown = true;
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 20, 10);
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, 11, 0);
}
```

But, it doesn't work.
Here is video, you can see from `ctrlPressedHalf` variable that I'm pressing crouch:
https://youtu.be/W4kXkOO15X0

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should remove these variables:

```
public bool ctrlPressed = false;
public bool ctrlPressedHalf = false;
public bool crouchTimeRunning = false;
public bool crouchOnCoolDown = false;
public bool crouchAvailable = true;
```

They all seem to be unneccessary here. You will need one boolean here though:

```
bool isCrouching = false;
```

Next, you will need one if statement for crouching (the statement will be executed while the user is holding the left ctrl button):

```
    //continue crouching if the player is already crouching and holding the left control button
//timer will affect this if statement if the player is not crouching and clicks the left control button
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && (timer <= 0 || isCrouching)) 
        { 
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
        //if I understood correctly, the two lines above were responsible for making a game object crouch
        timer = 3f; 
        isCrouching = true;
        }
        else
        {
        isCrouching = false;
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        //whatever code you had there that would make a game object stop crouching
        }
```

Comment: Okay, I try this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does your crouching animation clip have an exit time? I'll start by turn it to false. Also, have your transistion duration equal to zero from crouching to standing. If you haven't create any animator component, I'll recommend doing that. It might work better this way. From animator, you will be able to create different animations. Once your animations are made, Unity provides options to manipulate positions, scale and even rotation during the clip.